# Why is my bootstrp carousel not showing my images and it looks the way it does once i load it in my browser?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id="container-fluid">
<hgroup>
<h1> <a href="index.html" title="Love Forever"><span   class="header1">True Love Endures Forever</span> </h1>
</hgroup>
</header>
<nav  class="navbar navbar-default">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
   </nav >
<section class="container-fluid">
 <article>
<!-- Half Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "4"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "5"></li>
    </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
        <img src="../Images/golfin_2.jpg'" >
        <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Spending quality time with my baby at miniture golf.</h3>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="item">
       <img src="../Images/pink and black_2.jpg'" >
           <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Rocking pink and and black at Tyler's propasal to Mulenga.</h3>
  </div>                                
   </div>
    <div class="item">
<img src="../Images/convention foodtime_2.jpg'" >
       <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Went out to eat after 1st day of convention. Its was Good!</h3>
  </div>                                
 </div>
 <div class="item">
 <img src="../Images/Wifey and Me 1_2.jpg'" >
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Ally and I at Tyler and Mulenga's Wedding.</h3>
  </div>
<div class="item">
<img src="../Images/truelove_2.jpg'" >
</div>
<div class="carousel-caption">
     <h3>Our fist moment in PA. First photo together</h3>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <img src="../Images/first date_2.jpg'" >
</div>
<div class="carousel-caption">
 <h3>First date out in feild service</h3>
    </div>
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
 <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>

<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </article>
 </section>
  <footer class="footer container-fluid">
  <p>Hope you enjoy my main practice page. Its only the beginning!</p>
  </footer>
  <script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[This is a picture of how my site looks now. As you can see, no images are showing up and the half page carousel is not taking up half the space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6j0I.png)
I am looking forward to your helpful suggestions. I am open to anything.

Comment: May be **image** not found properly try inspect element.......

Comment: how do you fix this issue?

Comment: I use developer tools like Firefox developer edition and built in inspect element system to find out front end bug and fixing issue

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Carousal Example! try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EvzEpEi.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VzV3NwJ.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the problem is with your js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id="container-fluid">
<hgroup>
<h1> <a href="index.html" title="Love Forever"><span   class="header1">True Love Endures Forever</span> </h1>
</hgroup>
</header>
<nav  class="navbar navbar-default">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
   </nav >
<section class="container-fluid">
 <article>
<!-- Half Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "4"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "5"></li>
    </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/r_dc/caplio/r7/img/sample_04.jpg" >
        <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Spending quality time with my baby at miniture golf.</h3>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="item">
       <img src="http://www.seoghostwriter.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_151/rotator/sample-4.jpg" >
           <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Rocking pink and and black at Tyler's propasal to Mulenga.</h3>
  </div>                                
   </div>
    <div class="item">
<img src="http://www.gloriana.com/sites/g/files/g2000004666/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" >
       <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Went out to eat after 1st day of convention. Its was Good!</h3>
  </div>                                
 </div>
<div class="carousel-caption">
 <h3>First date out in feild service</h3>
    </div>
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </article>
 </section>
  <footer class="footer container-fluid">
  <p>Hope you enjoy my main practice page. Its only the beginning!</p>
  </footer>
 </body>
 </html>

By changing the link below of the js it works fine and displays the image for me. Try changing the links
```